# Error termination while performing NTO analysis in G09?

Tags: computational-chemistry, gaussian, symmetry

I'm trying to perform an NTO analysis (Natural transition orbitals) for my system. I first used TDDFT to calculate the excited states and then generated my chk file and copied it under the name of state_3.chk. I seemed to get a 2070 error.

**Input**

`%chk=state_3.chk # B3LYP/6-31G* Geom=AllCheck Guess=(Read,Only) Density=(Check,Transition=3) Pop=(Minimal,NTO,SaveNTO)`

**Error**

```
 dumping /fiocom/, unit = 3 NFiles =     1 SizExt =    524288 WInBlk =       512
                   defal = T LstWrd =       67072 FType=2 FMxFil=10000

 Number           0
 Base         20480
 End          67072
 End1         67072
 Wr Pntr      20480
 Rd Pntr      20480
 Length       46592
 Error termination in NtrErr:
 NtrErr Called from FileIO.
```

Comment: Usually, when the output file ends with "NtrErr Called from FileIO", the final part of the output file (~a few hundred lines) does not contain any information about the source of the error. You have to scroll up and skip all the "dumping /.../" messages in order to find the real cause of the error.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, and I'm sorry that it was the only +1 you got, but can you let us know if you figured this out now? Was wzkchem5's comment helpful? It's been 6+ months so it would be nice to get an update!

Comment: thanks for the answer  sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [comment by wzkchem5](Usually, when the output file ends with "NtrErr Called from FileIO", the final part of the output file (~a few hundred lines) does not contain any information about the source of the error. You have to scroll up and skip all the "dumping /.../" messages in order to find the real cause of the error.):

> "Usually, when the output file ends with "NtrErr Called from FileIO", the final part of the output file (~a few hundred lines) does not contain any information about the source of the error. You have to scroll up and skip all the "dumping /.../" messages in order to find the real cause of the error."